# Geometric Derivation of Lorentz Transformation

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

In Schutz (2nd edition) on page 22 at the top it states:

$t'= α(t − vx)$ and $x'= σ(x − vt)$

Fig. 1.4, see below, gives us one other bit of information: events $(t' = 0, x' = a)$ and $(t' = a, x'= 0)$ are
connected by a light ray. This can easily be shown to imply that $α = σ$. Please explain why $α = σ$

[image: Figure 1.4]

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Given $t'= \alpha(t − vx)$ and $x'= \sigma(x − vt)$, write
$$\Delta t'= \alpha(\Delta t − v\Delta x)\\ \Delta x'= \sigma(\Delta x − v\Delta t),$$

Using the light ray joining events $\scr P$ and $\scr R$, we have
$\Delta x' = -\Delta t'$
(that is, $\frac{\Delta x'}{\Delta t'}=-1$).

If we require for this light ray that $\Delta x=-\Delta t$
(that is, $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=-1$)
is also true,
then,
by substituting this for $\Delta x$ on the right-hand sides, we have
$$\Delta t'= \alpha(\Delta t − v(-\Delta t))=\alpha((1+v)\Delta t)\\ \Delta x'= \sigma((-\Delta t) − v\Delta t)=\sigma(-(1+v)\Delta t).$$

Since (from that light ray) we have $\Delta x' = -\Delta t'$,
then we find that we need $\alpha=\sigma$.

(By the way, in my opinion, I wouldn't call this a "geometric derivation".
Although it references a spacetime diagram,
it's more algebraic than geometric.)

Comment: This. In the abstract language of linear algebra Schutz is trying to point out that you have two eigenvectors already: forward and backward light rays $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(1,-1,0,0)$... So the 1+1D essence must be$$
\mathbf L=\frac12 \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}
\\= \frac12\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1+\lambda_2&\lambda_1-\lambda_2\\\lambda_1-\lambda_2&\lambda_1+\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}
$$ and so $L_{00}=\alpha=\lambda_1+\lambda_2=L_{11}=\sigma.$

Comment: @CRDrost Thanks. While true, I don't see Schutz using anything like this in his presentation. (Thus, I don't think Schutz would expect this method to be used by the reader to "easily show" the result.) However, along the lines of your comment, it would be good to point out that the eigenvalues are the Doppler-factor and its reciprocal (since the determinant equals one). Then, recognizing that the Doppler factor can be expressed as $\exp\theta$ (where $\theta$ is the rapidity), then sum of the eigenvalues is easily seen to be $2\cosh\theta$, which is twice the time-dilation factor $2\alpha$.

Comment: Yeah Schutz is not being that direct... It is just a shorthand way to write the argument, and to see why the *backwards mess* of the light pulse considered has to be crucial